# Can I use a placeholder to dynamically add text to a string imported from a property file with Spring's @Value annotation

Tags: spring, properties, annotations

Does anyone know if I can use placeholders with Spring's @Value annotion?

For example:

```
@Value("${a.url.from.propertiesFile}")
private void setUrl(String myUrlFromProperties) 
{
    this.url = myUrlFromProperties;
}
```

where my properties file would have:

```
a.url.from.propertiesFile=/firstPartOfUrl{dynamicBitToAddTo}restOfUrl
```

Comment: Doh! This was a pretty obvious solution really...just used this: String urlToUse = url.replace("{dynamicBitToAddTo}", "actualDynamicBitofUrl");

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

In this case if you have passed a null value in the parameter then the default value will be taken as defined with the annotation @Value.

But if you are passing a not null value in the parameter then it will not take the default value.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The code you have shown in your question is itself the example. It is how its done. :)

Comment: Ah OK sorry, I thought you were referring to a different approach.